# Conversion of voltage of battery

Tags: batteries, voltage, resistors

I have 9 volts battery. What resistance do I need to have 5 volts. And how to calculate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know the current you will draw, and then use Ohm's law to calculate the resistance. For example, if you draw 4 mA then the resistance will be 1000 Ohm.

However, as the current used by your circuit may vary, using a simple resistor will allow the voltage to vary: if the current drops 50%, your circuit will see 7V. If the current doubles, it will see only 3 V.

Because of this you really need to use some kind of voltage regulator - as Grant suggested while I am typing this.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping the voltage with a resistor is impractical except for extremely low currents.

Your best bet would be a lm7805.  9v goes in 5v comes out.  They are quite cheap and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answers on top are directly what you asked for, what you really need here is a regulator, such as the 7805 or something newer (and better) that can properly regulate the voltage to 5V. Using fixed resistors is a problem because as the load changes, so does the voltage.

Comment: The voltage of a 9V battery drops pretty quickly, and some 7805's need 3V headroom. Combined with a the output voltage inaccuracy this leads to a 9V battery being unsuitable very quickly. Better suggest a low-dropout regulator, for instance an LM2940.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends highly on what you want to use the 5V for. Any resistance in the down wind circuit that puts a load on the voltage divider will change the voltage. Here is a circuit that will put 5V at the resistor divider node assuming that the 5V feeds into a very high resistance load - if not infinite.

[image]

Comment: Use of 1% precision resistors is not necessary when using 1k2 and 1k5. There are various other combinations that come very close.

Comment: @jippie - On what grounds do you claim that 1% resistors are not needed? One can build a circuit with what ever precision that we feel is suitable to the design at hand. Just because you may choose 1.2K and 1.5K resistors to achieve a 0.8 ratio makes them no more accurate at lower tolerance than my selection of 4K and 5K to get to the same 0.8 ratio using 1% parts.

Comment: 1% is silly when the battery is nowhere near that accurate. Even if it was, as soon as you put a load on the 5V output it will change. The output impedance of your source is 2.2 kOhm, so just 1 mA will drop it by 2.2 V. To keep the 5 V within 1 % you can't load it with more than 23 uA, or about 220 kOhms.

Comment: exactly my point.